# Store time in variable

Tags: java, netbeans

In my query I want to store the current system time  in b variable so that I can compare the variable with another time to execute the following conditions.. Please help me in my coding..

```
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        String user=txtid.getText();
        String pwd=new String (passwordfld.getPassword());
        int loop=0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String uname=rs.getString("Emp_ID");
            String password=rs.getString("Password");
            if ((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(password)))
            {
                st.executeUpdate("insert into Attendance (Emp_ID,Date,Time_in) Values ('"+user+"',curdate(),curtime());");


                s.executeUpdate("update Attendance set Late='Yes' where emp_id='"+user+"' and date=curdate() and time_in>'23:15:00';");
                s.executeUpdate("update Attendance set Late='No' where emp_id='"+user+"' and date=curdate() and time_in<'23:15:00';");


                Time b=new Time();


                if (b>08:40:00)
                {
                   s.executeUpdate("update Attendance set Late='Yes' where emp_id='"+user+"' and date=curdate();");
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OOps You are late..!!");
                 }
                else
                {
                   s.executeUpdate("update Attendance set Late='No' where emp_id='"+user+"' and date=curdate();");
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HAve a niCe daY");
                dispose();
                new Home().setVisible(true);
                loop++;
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        if (loop==0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password not in database!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Please look into `PreparedStatement` to save yourself from `SQL injection`.

Comment: Please include your table schema, and example values used as date and time inside the table

Comment: You can use `java.util.Date` variable.

Comment: `if (b>08:40:00)` illegal in java. I don't know what `Time` class is. So cant suggest how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 8 && c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) >= 40) {//if you want 8PM then replace 8 with 20.
  System.out.println("Hello time now is greater than 8:40AM");
}
```